# Redis or Hazelcast, or others?

Tags: caching, redis, distributed, hazelcast

I took an old web application recently. The App will save a lot of object into Ehcache at init time.And then obtain the object from the cache. And now, the object has increased many times. Ehcache in the app can not meet the requirement. So, we consider using a distributed cache. We will set some strategies and let the objects save in different cache server.
Redis and Hazelcast are both good. Question is, the Redis and Hazelcast compared to the previous Ehcache, Redis and Hazelcast must **Serialize**  objects.  May be it will consume more time.
So which is better? 
Or are there no other better alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What are your requirements? Hazelcast has pluggable serialization and there are serialization libraries like FlatBuffers that are exceedingly fast if needed.

Hazelcast is ideal if you are Java centric, of course you can also access Hazelcast via .Net CLR languages if you are using Hazelcast Enterprise.

Hazelcast is more than just a simple distributed cache, you can also leverage the distributed CPUs in your cluster and execute processes directly in the grid, which can result in very high performance.

If you are multi-language and dont need to execute code on top of distributed data (in-memory executor service, mapreduce or entryprocessors) Redis would make sense.

Comment: Thank you.We will use the cache like a **calculator**. It will load more data from database. Then a dispatcher will send request to different calculator(cache node).The client use all values form each calculator,and sum them.If the cache can't receive request, may be we will use Tomcat and deploy web app.

Comment: I think you missed [Redisson](https://redisson.org) lib. Which allow to use MapReduce and Executor/Scheduler services on top of Redis.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Redisson](https://redisson.org) - Redis based In-Memory Data Grid is a good alternative for Ehcache. Provides a lot data serialization codecs like:

`Jackson JSON`, `Avro`, `Smile`, `CBOR`, `MsgPack`, `Amazon Ion`, `Kryo`, `JDK Serialization`, `LZ4` and `Snappy`.

It also allows to store Map data in external storage along with Redis store using `Read-through`, `Write-through` and `Write-behind` strategies.

Offers distributed MapReduce and Executor/Scheduler services.